# Can I span a gap between pipes with heat tape?

Tags: heating

I have hot and cold lines running parallel to each other.  Can I start heat tape on one line and then "jump" 4 inches to the other line to finish the installation in order to use the entire length of a 3 foot heat tape run

Comment: It's probably going to depend on the brand. Did you read the literature?

Comment: Yes, you can do this but be sure that it's ok to use this particular tape on a HOT water line.  Some are designed for this and others can be damaged by being wrapped around too hot a pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Brand I am going to use would be Easy Heat.  I didn't see anything on the packaging about hot water pipes, but will double check.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of heat tape the self regulating type can be in open air and even cross over itself. This type changes its resistance based on temp so it won’t overheat.
The current based type more similar to lots of small resistors creats heat and depending on brand most can not handle non contact or wrapping on top of itself.

I would verify what the manufacturer states as things may of changed since I started purchasing self regulating heat tape about 15 years ago.

The self regulation is not the temp sensor in the cord that is used to reduce energy consumption with temps above freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if it’s self regulating heat trace like , Raychem Xl or Chromalox Cpr , SLR
Cable . Both have max of  185 degrees temperature sheath .
On the open cable install some flexible soft conduit , insulate with a Armaflex over the seal tite .